# What is the module field in the identity inspector used for?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sdk

What is the module field in the identity inspector used for?  In Xcode, there is a field under the class name when you switch to the identity inspector.  I understand the class field is for selecting the class but not too sure what the module field is for. you can see the below screenshot

[image: image of Xcode's identity inspector]

Answer (score 1):

This is taken from the [2014 WWDC discussion](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/401/)

> Now, you may notice there's a new module field here.
>
> Another great way that Swift improves the coding experience is by
>   associating classes with the modules that they are declared in.
>
> That allows you to use short, comfortable class names while still
>   ensuring that your classes won't collide across targets and projects.